# 5 second delay caused by itok

Tags: media

I recently noticed a 5 second delay on my Drupal 7.34 website which I think is being caused by itok (a new security token used for files, like images, that are modified by Drupal).  How do I remove this delay?  Do I have to disable itok?

For instance [this image](http://www.energyjustice.net/system/files/styles/large/private/ssc-no-smokestack.jpg?itok=_XoPM7lj) takes 5 seconds to load.

Answer (score 2):

If you can, look instead at serving the image as a public file, so that your webserver can return it directly without loading Drupal at all for that request. Instead of seeing `system/files` in the path, you'd see a path to the actual image file on your server - eg `sites/default/files/`.

Review whether it's necessary to serve images using the Private download method, which introduces a Drupal bootstrap and access controls on all static file requests. The default for this is configurable at `admin/config/media/file-system`.

It may be you're seeing a delay across all requests handled by Drupal, and have noticed it because you'd expect serving a static file to be quicker than that? Note that requests for static files (eg [your logo](http://www.energyjustice.net/files/energyjustice_15.png)) are not similarly affected, but for me I see ~6s response time checking the more basic pages on your site (eg `curl --head` against your donate page).

Is your server overloaded, or do you have modules enabled which might be performing time-consuming operations (eg network activity, DNS lookup, ...) for every request?

[A patch in d.o#2089789](https://www.drupal.org/node/2089789) gives you a means to remove the `itok` token if you do need to serve that image after checking Drupal's access controls.

The reasons for introducing itok are discussed in the [Drupal 7.20 release notes](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-7.20-release-notes).

Comment: The server isn't overloaded.  It is possible that another module is causing problems as well.  The five second delay is the same whether I check at peak usage hours or at 2am.

Comment: Sure, just speculating :) I've updated answer to clarify that you might be able to switch to using Public file downloads at `admin/config/media/file-system` - this might not suit your use case, but certainly static files are worth serving directly if possible for best performance.

Comment: So the 5 second delay might be caused by Drupal requests.  In which case doing static image fetches would improve the situation, but not get rid of the base 5 second delay for a page without images.

Comment: I disabled all the modules except the basic ones and still have a 5 second delay.

Comment: You're going to have to roll up your sleeves and debug I think. DB initialisation? Reverse DNS? Hosting platform? You need more information than just guesses off the internet I think :) Who is it hosted with?

Comment: I'm using a VPS on JaguarPC with Centos, Apache, 2.2.26, and PHP 5.2.9.  My own custom PHP/MySQL software runs fine on the server.

I tried replacing my custom .htaccess file with the default one but that didn't help.